# Getting only grub prompt after installing dual boot Windows 7 then Ubuntu and EasyBCD

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, grub, mbr, easybcd

I'm having an annoying problem. I installed Windows 7 a long time ago, yesterday I installed Ubuntu 10.04. After installing the Ubuntu, it was working great (I got the grub boot menu and everything) but the Windows 7 didn't boot.

After reading many comments over the web, I did a recovery for the MBR and Windows 7 was loading without a dual boot menu (no surprise over there).

Then I installed the EasyBCD and set it up like instructed over the web (adding the Linux to the MBR and setting grab2).

Now I am getting the menu but when I try to boot Ubuntu, I only get the GRUB prompt?!

I can't find anything to help me over the web.....

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2, specifically the section titled **Reinstalling GRUB2**. Cut to the chase and try the chroot method first.

If that fails you can still revert to legacy GRUB (remove grub2 and install the previous version from within the chrooted environment). I had a similar problem with a particular machine when ubuntu first shipped GRUB2, and this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple grub2 installation

Example of grub2 installing on **/dev/sda1**

```
grub-install --root-directory=/ /dev/sda1
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

or

```
update-grub2
```

Make sure grub is pointing to your **root** ***/*** in ubuntu for grub2 to use that grub.cfg. If not you will get a grub prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found the answer.

If you have two HD and want to install both WIN7 and Ubuntu U have to specify them for deferent HDs (the boot sector at list).

This solves the problem.

otherwise I've tried every thing else out there and didn't work for me....

Erez